# Running asynchronous code inside JMS queue listener onMessage method

Tags: spring-boot, jms, message-queue, spring-jms

In my application I'm posting JMS messages into a queue which represent tasks to be performed. When the `onMessage` method of the listener is invoked, the task which I need to perform automatically runs in its own thread, so it's asynchronous.

The application is written on Spring Boot and I'm using Kubernetes for container orchestration, in order to dynamically adjust the number of worker processes.

I've seen examples of implementing this kind of pattern of worker queue and JMS listener and I have always seen synchronous methods being called inside the `onMessage` method.

So, my question is: is it better to wait until the asynchronous operation completes before returning on the `onMessage`callback?

Thank you

Comment: You need to outline what "better" actually means here. What criteria are you considering when determining if one approach is "better" than another? This question, as it is currently constructed, is going to elicit discussion and opinion-based answers rather than fact-based answers which means it's off-topic here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's generally not a good idea to perform async processing on the listener thread.

If you want to increase concurrency, increase the container's concurrency instead (to create multiple consumers).

If you MUST go async for some reason, you should hold up the listener thread until the process completes, to avoid message loss in the event of a failure.

In addition, if you exit the listener, you will likely get a new message before the current one completes. Even if using CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE, you could acknowledge messages out of order, or you have to keep track of unacknowledged messages.

Generally, it's just simpler to do the work on the listener thread(s).